# How memory space is saved in bitwise operator?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I want to know how memory space is saved by using bitwise operator in C i.e:if for a bit string of TRUE/FALSE value how the use of bitoperation save memory space?

Comment: There is no memory involved in an operator.

Comment: No I want to say that how bitwise operator use save memory space?

Comment: It is not used to save space. It is used to manipulate bit values.

Comment: Should we assume for the remainder of this dialogue you mean *bit fields* ? If not, the question itself makes little sense.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to re-interpret your question, as it appears that you are inquiring about using bits as data, and utilizing bit-wise operators to manipulate these data bits. If this is what you are asking then the answer is simple:

A single byte can hold 8 boolean values of data. For comparison, in C# using the Boolean data type the same 8 boolean values would take at least 8 bytes to store.

In C, a common practice to store various states is to do something like this:

```
/* Define distinct states (or booleans, flags, etc. */
const unsigned char state1 = 0x01; // hex for 0000 0001
const unsigned char state2 = 0x02; // hex for 0000 0010
const unsigned char state3 = 0x04; // hex for 0000 0100
const unsigned char state4 = 0x08; // hex for 0000 1000


unsigned char mystate = 0;

/* Use bitwise operators to manipulate */
mystate |= state1; /* turn state 1 on. */

/* test state */
if (mystate & state1)
     printf("State1 set\n");

/* clear state */
mystate &= ~state1; /* turn state 1 off. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators themselves aren't inherently memory operators, but they can help save space in certain situations.

For instance, to save space multiple boolean variables could be stored in a single 8-bit int variable by using each bit to represent a true/false value. Then you can extract the bits by masking or shift operators.

Another example might be in programming [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) units where some instructions, such as subtraction, are left out since a subtraction can be emulated by the addition of two values where one of them is negated (via two's complement). For example, take `7-12 = -5`. `7` is `0000 1111` while `12` is `0000 1010`. Two's complement tells us that to represent a negative number, we negate the binary of the positive value and add `1`, so `-12` is `1111 0100`, and the subsequent addition gets us `1111 1011`, which is -5. We know it's negative number because the most significant bit (i.e. the left-most bit is 1), so we can find the value of `1111 1011` the same way we did before. You see workarounds like this done a lot in architecture and low-level languages such as assembly to save space, reduce cost, and speed things up.

Comment: yah..I ask the same question.But I cannot express in words.

Comment: Will you explain with a example@henrymei

Comment: Sure, one of the other answers already shows the boolean example. I can show you a quick example of subtraction through addition w/ two's complement.

Comment: I cannot understand :mystate |= state1; in the above program.I am new in programming field .Will you please illaborate?

Comment: `=|` is a shortcut to say `mystate = mystate | state1'. That is assign `mystate` the result of taking the `OR` operator of itself with `state1'.

Comment: that means mystate=mystate+(bitwise or) state1?

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 bits in a byte. There are at least 32 bits in an `int`. And so on. If you don't need all of those bits for some value, e.g. a boolean or a small number, you can avoid wasting bits by packing multiple values into a single variable.

However, note that the act of packing and extracting these data mandate runtime calculation costs, so it's usually a trade-off of space efficiency vs. calculation speed.

Most people writing for modern general-purpose systems don't worry about packing data because CPU speed is cheap compared to the time it takes to write - and later read - all that bit-twiddling code, so human time is often more important than CPU time.

Basically, don't worry about packing/bitfields unless you know you have a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators do not by themselves "save memory space". Bitwise operators are low-level *tools* that can be used to solve achieve many different objectives, and "saving memory space" is just one of these objectives.

Bitwise operators can be used for what I'd call *manual implementation of bit-fields*. By using bitwise operators one can pack several small-bit-width values into a single 32- or 64-bit-wide machine word.

For example, when one needs to store a 3-bit value, 10-bit value and 20-bit value, one can stuff all of them into a single 32-bit object (`unsigned int` and such). So, instead of declaring three different `unsigned int` variables one can get by by using only one, thus reducing memory consumed by these pieces of data three times.

Maybe an even better example would be 32 variables of type `bool`, which typically occupy 32 bytes of memory. But by using bitwise operators one can store all these boolean values inside one 32-bit integer variable, reducing memory consumption by the factor of 8.

This is actually exactly what a typical compiler does under the hood when one uses bit-fields. If for some reason one does not want to use bit-fields (and ion some contexts there are good reasons not to use them), one can implement the identical value-packing functionality through bitwise operations.